# Pandas: Use a dataframe to index another one and fill the gaps?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, match, fill

I have two dataframes. df_0 is a complete list of dates and df_1 is a generic register indexed by incomplete dates. I need to make a dataframe that has df_0’s complete dates as an index, filled with df_1’s register in the matching dates. For dates without a register entry, I just need to repeat the last date’s register data as a filler. Any ideas on how to make this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add sample data with desired output

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with parameter `method`:

```
df = df_1.reindex(df_0.index, method="ffill")
```

Answer (score 0):

use 'reindex' to expand the df_1 and use 'fillna' to fill in the missed valued.

```
df_2 = df_1.reindex(df_0.index).fillna(method="ffill")
```